# Bootstrap table with JSON data not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I am trying to save data from a link in JSON format and pass that data to the Bootstrap table but its not working properly

I can see the data in console and if I use `data-url` than it works fine but I want to save data in a variable and use that data in table.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0apn10v9/1/)

If I use this code than it works fine, but I want to save data into a variable first and than assign it to table.

```
$.get("https://api.github.com/users/wenzhixin/repos", function(data){
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data
    });
});
```

Comment: can you give me the demo URL link for the bootstap table with ajax?

Comment: @HarshSanghani [here is one](http://jsfiddle.net/8svjf80g/383/) with .get method which is similar to ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned the only idea to store the data into a variable is for re-useablity you can do below. **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0apn10v9/5/)**

```
   var jsonDataCall ;      // keep a global variable in the scope.

   $(function() { 
    $.get("https://api.github.com/users/wenzhixin/repos", function(result){
        jsonDataCall = result;   // save it to a variable for later use
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            data: jsonDataCall   // use the same variable to build the table
        });
    });
   });
```

By the way `async` is deprecated and you shouldn't be using it anymore [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448011/jquery-ajax-methods-async-option-deprecated-what-now) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680897/jquery-ajax-async-false-causes-a-strange-warning)

---

**Explaining problem in your code provided in jsfiddle:**

```
var jsonDataCall = $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/wenzhixin/repos", function(result){
        jsonDataCall =result;
    });

var jsonData = $.ajax({    // this variable is not used anywhere in the code.
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/wenzhixin/repos",
        success: function(result) {
            jsonData = result;
        }
    });

$(function () {
      var $table = $('#randomTable').bootstrapTable({data: jsonDataCall});
 });
```

This line `var $table = $('#randomTable').bootstrapTable({data: jsonDataCall});` kicks off on document ready. And here we have `jsonDataCall` which will access the value in it. But in the first line you have assigned a ajax method to this variable and not a value. So the in the above line `data: jsonDataCall` will try to **assign the ajax function to data variable** it does not assign the value returned from server because it comes later after the ajax success has executed.

**Solution:** When ever you are dealing with ajax calls you must make sure all the code that depends on the returned server result should kick off in the ajax success else you are in trouble.

Comment: it worked fine. I still could not understand whats the difference between your answer and HarshSanghani answer. I meant what's the adv and disadv in answers.

Comment: @MikeRoss the difference is this answer does not use `async` which is deprecated and must not be used.. which is the case in the other answer and in your fiddle.

Comment: @MikeRoss I updated the fiddle.. I had forgot to remove the ajax call which was not neccesary.

Comment: @MikeRoss I put explanation .. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Just change your jQuery code with following :-

```
var jsonData;

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/wenzhixin/repos",
    success: function(result) {
        jsonData = result;
    }
});

$(function () {
        $('#randomTable').bootstrapTable({data: jsonData});
});

function queryParams() {
    return {
        type: 'owner',
        sort: 'updated',
        direction: 'desc',
        per_page: 100,
        page: 1
    };
}
```

I have stored the Ajax response data into one variable and then add SetTimeout while assigning the data to bootstrap table.

It may help you.

Comment: and also removed the one extra ajax call. Let me know its helpfull to you or not.

Comment: This is not a solution its a workaround.. If the ajax request takes more than 1 sec (1000) this solution wont work

Comment: @Reddy I have not added only setTimeout also change the function, Please see before making vote.

Comment: @reddy ok so what should i do here? is there any other way??

Comment: @MikeRoss what is the idea behind storing the value in a variable and then assigning it to the table? any plan of reusing the data?

Comment: @Reddy If You remove the settimeout from the my answer then also It works, Because I have change the code in function also.

Comment: So there is setTimeout doesn't matter

Comment: @Reddy what OP trying to is set full AJAX call in one variable and then set this variable to the bootstrap datatable which is wrong, So I just make that correct and it's work.

Comment: @Reddy You are just useless async : false is from the OP, I have not added , Please check atleast jsfiddle.

Comment: @Reddy yes i want to reuse the data for filtering purpose so i dont have to make call to api for filtering purpose. thats why i want to store it in a variable

Comment: @MikeRoss ok I understand. let me provide a solution.

Comment: @reddy i only want to store the data in JSON format in any variable so i can use it for filtering purpose later on and dont have to make server call.

Comment: @MikeRoss can you just tell me what is the problem with this answer? is there any problem?

Comment: @HarshSanghani no problem just want to know which one is efecient for my website thats all. Can you justify why your answer is more suitable that his answer?

Comment: @HarshSanghani just by downvoting my answer doesn't make your answer any better.

Comment: What he is done store result variable in jsonDataCall and then set  jsonDataCall to bootstrap table, You can directly stored the result variable to the bootstrap datatable.

Comment: @Reddy I am not interested to vote your answer, So there is not point of negative, I like to help others only.

Comment: `*What he is done store result variable in jsonDataCall and then set jsonDataCall to bootstrap table, You can directly stored the result variable to the bootstrap datatable.*` if he directly sets the result variable into the table how can he reuse the data? which is what the OP is trying to acheive.